# Well documented NLP libraries in any language supporting Slovan languages?

Tags: nlp, text-analysis

Do you have any tips of well documented, developer friendly NLP libraries for text analysis (morphology, text concept) for Slovan languages like **Czech**, Polish etc?

The API could be in any language - java, python, c, node, whatever.

Nice lib for stemming as an example could be this one: https://github.com/dundalek/czech-stemmer

I am studying the best options for text analysis. I want to be able to get most out of a sentence in specific topic. Let's say that i will have medical sentence and thanks to my dictionary words in the databases I will be able to do analysis based on NLP algorithm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [polyglot](http://polyglot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). it supports both Polish and Czech.

Comment: It looks nice, but I have problems installing some of the models supporting Czech or other languages. Do you know of some demos and working apps or git repos? thanks!